# User can switch account to another user

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have an url `path('dashboard/<int:user_id>/', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),`

The problem is when User is logged in, he can change `user_id` variable in url and switch to another user account. My question is how to prevent that behaviour.

Should I change something in template or somewhere else ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should *not* pass the `user_id` in the URL then. You can use `request.user` to obtain the logged in user:

```
# app/urls.py

from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('dashboard/', views.dashboard, name='dashboard')
]
```

in your views, you can thus work with the `request.user`:

```
# app/views.py

from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def dashboard(request):
    myuser = request.user
    # ...
```

By using the [**`@login_required`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator) you prevent the view from being triggered if no user has been logged in.